Module not found: Can't resolve './Home.module.scss'
При попытке задеплоить с помощью Vercel проект с Github репозитория вылетает ошибка:
Failed to compile.
./src/app/Home.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve './Home.module.scss'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
> Build failed because of webpack errors
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

При этом если у себя в терминале введу pnpm build - всё работает прекрасно.
Бьюсь третий час над проблемой и никакие варианты не помогают.
Помогите!
Ссылка на репо: https://github.com/Qaddis/dl-guard
Структура репо:


Для всех, у кого возникнет схожая проблема - решение элементарное. Никакие конфиги менять не надо.
НУЖНО ПРОСТО ПЕРЕИМЕНОВАТЬ ВСЕ ФАЙЛЫ module.scss.
Если у вас есть файл Home.module.scss, то переименовать его нужно в home.module.scss, и обновить импорты в компонентах. И так ВЕЗДЕ.
